# mvvm light running an action on property changed

Tags: mvvm-light

I'd like to run an action on Property changed.

Something like `RunActionOnPropertyChanged(this.Property, x => SomeAction);`

Is there anything within MVVM Light that cant help with this?

I have looked into the messaging but it seems a little over kill for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing native to MVVM Light that does this.

Sounds like you just want to subscribe to the NotifyPropertyChanged Event and execute an action when the appropriate property raises a change.